# Spring XD - Mail source configuration - how to provide password

Tags: email, configuration, spring-xd

I created a mailstream with following command -------

```
stream create --name mailstream --definition "mail --host=imap.gmail.com --username=yyyyyyyy12@gmail.com --password=my password | file --dir=/tmp/gmailData" --deploy
```

Refer -http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#modules

But in the xd-singletone console I get -

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
```

How to resolve this issue.

Also --password=secret  - how to keep my password invisible or secret in the XD shell

/shankha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape "@" with "%40" for both username and password and to specify `--port=993` for gmail. Also, it may be possible not to work with the default settings as GMail requires SSL for imap and this needs to be configured as well.

So, I would suggest the following (basically, creating a new source module):

1. Go to `spring-xd-1.0.0.M6\xd\modules\source` and make a copy of `mail` folder and name this copy `gmail`
2. Go to `spring-xd-1.0.0.M6\xd\modules\source\gmail\config` and rename both `mail.properties` and `mail.xml` to `gmail.properties` and `gmail.xml` respectively
3. Inside `gmail.xml` replace everything with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <channel id="output" />

    <int-mail:mail-to-string-transformer
        charset="${charset}" input-channel="transform" output-channel="output" />

    <beans:beans profile="use-polling">
        <int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter
            store-uri="${protocol}://${username:}:${password:}@${host}:${port}/${folder}"
            channel="transform" should-mark-messages-as-read="${markAsRead}"
            should-delete-messages="${delete}" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
            <poller fixed-delay="${fixedDelay}" time-unit="SECONDS">
                <advice-chain>
                    <beans:bean
                        class="org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.support.ThreadContextClassLoaderSetterAdvice" />
                </advice-chain>
            </poller>
        </int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
    </beans:beans>

    <beans:beans profile="use-idle">
        <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter
            store-uri="${protocol}://${username:}:${password:}@${host}:${port}/${folder}"
            channel="transform" auto-startup="true" mail-filter-expression="${expression}"
            should-mark-messages-as-read="${markAsRead}"
            should-delete-messages="${delete}"  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        </int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
    </beans:beans>

    <beans:beans profile="default">
        <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
            <beans:prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.debug">false</beans:prop>
        </util:properties>
    </beans:beans>
</beans:beans>
```

4. In XD shell now you will use something like the following to create your stream:

```
stream create --name myGmailStream --definition "gmail --host=imap.gmail.com --username=yyyyyyyy12%40gmail.com --password=my_password --port=993 | file --dir=/tmp/gmailData" --deploy
```

Here, please note the following:

- I added `--port=993`
- the username contains "%40" instead of "@"
- the definition of the stream starts with `"gmail`
- if your password contains "@" you need to replace that with "%40" as well

What I've done above is to, basically, create a new custom module (a source) which is kind of easy (more details about this you can find in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M6/reference/html/#_creating_a_module)). The XD single node or the XD Shell doesn't even need to be restarted. Give it a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you .. It works. But how I protect my password ?  Because in the stream create   command I provide my password with --password option.   I try to configure usrer name , password , host in the config/modules/source/gmail/gmail.properties............  But It fails .... How Can I go with property file

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the password that you don't want to appear as part of the stream definition, you can provide it as part of your mail module options, as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_module_configuration

ie

```
<xd_home>/config/modules/source/mail/mail.properties:

password: yourpassword
```