# Spring XD - mail sink configuration for outlook

Tags: outlook, spring-xd

I'm trying to configure Spring XD's mail sink to send messages to an outlook account.  This is my stream definition:

```
stream create outlookMailSink --definition "http | mail --to='\"email@address.com\"' --host=outlook.office365.com --subject=payload+' world'" --deploy
```

I'm testing using this shell command:

```
http post --data Hello
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
```

I have investigated this in the Spring XD documentation and internet searches but I haven't found a solution that works.  Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which involves creating a new mail sink module which is a slight modification of spring XD's supplied mail sink module. The stream must also include to, from, host, port, username and password options.

1. Copy the `..\spring-xd-<version>\xd\modules\sink\mail` folder and rename to secure-mail.
2. In `..\spring-xd-<version>\xd\modules\sink\secure-mail` rename both `mail.properties` and `mail.xml` to `secure-mail.properties` and `secure-mail.xml` respectively.
3. Replace the contents of `secure-mail.xml` with the following:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
   xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

   <channel id="input" />

   <int-mail:header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="send">
       <int-mail:to expression="${to:null}" />
       <int-mail:from expression="${from:null}" />
       <int-mail:subject expression="${subject:null}" />
       <int-mail:cc expression="${cc:null}" />
       <int-mail:bcc expression="${bcc:null}" />
       <int-mail:reply-to expression="${replyTo:null}" />
       <int-mail:content-type expression="${contentType:null}" />
   </int-mail:header-enricher>

   <channel id="send" />

   <int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter
       channel="send" host="${host}" port="${port}" username="${username:}"
       password="${password:}" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

   <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
       <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</beans:prop>
   </util:properties>

   </beans:beans>
   ```
4. Create the stream as follows:

   ```
   stream create outlookMailSink --definition "http | secure-mail --to='\"email@address.com\"' --from='\"email@address.com\"' --host=outlook.office365.com --port=587 --username=email@address.com --password=password --subject=payload+' world'" --deploy
   ```
5. Test using shell command: `http post --data Hello`

The contents of secure-mail.xml is almost identical to mail.xml, the key is to set the property `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` to be true in order to enable TLS encryption for communication over port 587. OF course you could just modify Spring XD's mail sink module directly and use this - it's up to you.

I'd be interested to hear if anyone has a better solution to this?  For example, is it possible to set the `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` property on start-up of Spring XD thereby allowing you to use the original mail sink module?  I tried this by modifying the xd-singlenode startup script - the property was set but it didn't affect the mail sink module.

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24765052/2124106
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23823863/2124106
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html